# How to use facebook catalog batch api properly?

Tags: facebook, post, python-requests, request, facebook-marketing-api

I would like to bulk delete some products using facebook catalog api. Based on the reference i created a request like below:

```
import json    
url="https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/my_catalog_id/items_batch"
headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}
params={"access_token":"my_token",
      "item_type": "PRODUCT_ITEM",
       "requests":[{
        "method": "DELETE",
        "data": {
          "id": "2634628"  # I added one product to test.
        }
      }]}
req=requests.post(url=url,params=json.dumps(params),headers=headers)
```

But it returns:

```
{'error': {'message': '(#100) The parameter requests is required', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 100, 'fbtrace_id': 'Awnx8cVOn-tCHOEbFDE'}}
```

Comment: Not sure if you are supposed to make the whole request as JSON; I'd try sending regular POST parameters.

Comment: hi, @CBroe I sent the "requests" part in the parameter named "data" and the access token in the parameter named params and the result was successful. (`req=requests.post(url=urlx,params=params,headers=headers,data=json.dumps(data))`). When I check the batch status, it shows as finished and there is no error. But the products still appear on the site. (i sent delete request). Do you have any idea about this ?